# Adding twilio dependency is returning xml as a response for all endpoints in application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, twilio

I am trying to send SMS through twilio. I am able to send message to the number but the problem is my entire application started sending xml as a response. It is effecting my entire application. How to convert so that I can get json as a response. I am new to this. Please someone help me.

sms is sending successfully but my entire application is started getting response as xml.

This is my Controller:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendmessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendmessage(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return userRegisterService.sendmessage(userDto.getMobileNumber(), userDto.getSmsMessage());
    }
```

This is my service class:

```java
    @PostConstruct
    private void setup() {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> sendmessage(String MobileNumber, String SmsMessage) {
        Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(MobileNumber), new PhoneNumber(OUTGOINGSMSNumber), SmsMessage).create();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Message sent successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have not written explicitly anywhere to convert to xml. Just adding twilio dependency is converting to xml for entire application.

Comment: put at least the code you're using to send the message

Answer (score 0):

According to Twilio documentation:

> By default, Twilio's REST API returns XML, with a root element of
> . For example, here is the default XML representation
> of a SMS message:

further reading : https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/twilios-response

use the API, apperently the Twilio Jar override spring configuration, if you want to continue using it annotate your spring controller by adding `produces` to `@RequestMapping`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = URI_PING,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Issue is arising with other endpoints due to adding twilio dependency. I don't have issue here. It is affecting other end points.

Comment: I tried this. This is not working. Anyways Thanks for the reply.

Comment: switch to use the API instead of the JAR I suppose

Comment: I commented the code and left the dependency uncommented. Leaving dependency also giving response as xml.

Comment: it's probably some hidden configuration. is  produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE  on every API not working

Comment: Can I use twilio without adding dependency. I mean can I use it indirectly?

Comment: yes look at https://www.twilio.com/fr/docs/usage/api and after that use RestTemplate or FeignClient to consume the API in your api